# Java Splay Tree rotate

Tags: java, splay-tree

Im working on a right rotate method for when i splay. I have nodes that i use to hold the value of the left child and the left childs right. On the case that im testing the left childs right is null but when i compile i get a null pointer exception. Even if the value is null shouldnt it just assign the new node to null rather than throw a null pointer exception?

below are my assignments

```
Node<E> leftC = x.getLeft();
Node<E> leftsRight = leftC.getRight();
```

in the case im testing, the tree looks like

```
     3
    /
   2
  /
 1
```

and x is 3, so then leftC is 2 and leftsRight should be null but it just throws the null pointer.

Why is it throwing the null pointer instead of just assigning it to null?

Comment: The most likely thing is that `x.getLeft()` is returning `null`, not 2. Then when you try to evaluate `leftC.getRight()`, `leftC` is `null`, which is causing the NPE. You can verify this in the debugger.

Comment: Assuming that the NullPointerException originates from one of the two lines you posted (verify it), then it means that either x is null, of leftC is null. There's no other option.